Macro is not calculating numbers correctly
My macro takes the dimensions in 3 columns (LxWxH) and finds the ceiling based on two parameters to make the dimensions more easily pivotable. However, any number over 241 calculates to 480 and I'm not sure why. I've played around the number variations at the top (above 192) but they all come out to 480. Any help is appreciated.
Sub Format__Dims()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell <> "" Then
            If cell.Value <= 48 Then
                cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(cell.Value, 48)
            Else
                If cell.Value > 48 And cell.Value <= 60 Then
                    cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(cell.Value, 60)
                Else
                    If cell.Value > 60 And cell.Value <= 70 Then
                        cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(cell.Value, 70)
                    Else
                        If cell.Value > 70 And cell.Value <= 80 Then
                            cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(cell.Value, 80)
                        Else
                            If cell.Value > 80 And cell.Value <= 90 Then
                                cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(cell.Value, 90)
                            Else
                                If cell.Value > 90 And cell.Value <= 96 Then
                                    cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(cell.Value, 96)
                                Else
                                    If cell.Value > 96 And cell.Value <= 100 Then
                                        cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(cell.Value, 100)
                                    Else
                                        If cell.Value > 100 And cell.Value <= 120 Then
                                            cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(cell.Value, 120)
                                        Else
                                            If cell.Value > 120 And cell.Value <= 144 Then
                                                cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(cell.Value, 144)
                                            Else
                                                If cell.Value > 144 And cell.Value <= 196 Then
                                                    cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(cell.Value, 196)
                                                Else
                                                    If cell.Value > 196 Then
                                                        cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(cell.Value, 240)
                                                    End If
                                                 End If
                                             End If
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column + 0).Insert
    
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range(Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(Lastrow, ActiveCell.Column)).FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(RC[2]:RC[3])"
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Select
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Copy
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column).PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues

    Columns(ActiveCell.Column + 0).Insert
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range(Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(Lastrow, ActiveCell.Column)).FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[2]:RC[3])"
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Select
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Copy
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column).PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "Max Length"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "Max width"
    
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column + 1).Select
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column).DELETE
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column).DELETE
    
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column - 2).Select
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column + 0).Insert
    
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range(Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(Lastrow, ActiveCell.Column)).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(TRIM(RC[1]),""x"",TRIM(RC[2]),""x"",TRIM(RC[3]))"

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "Dims"
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Select
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column).Copy
    Columns(ActiveCell.Column).PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub



What language is this written in? Please include the appropriate tech tags, the current tags are all generic programming/mathematical concepts.

This looks like Excel VBA, but is it?

It would probably help you debug if you used ElseIf.

Ceiling function - Returns number rounded up, away from zero, to the nearest multiple of significance. So, all numbers above 240 round up to a multiple of 240 following to the code If cell.Value > 196 Then cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(cell.Value, 240).

Change the code to If cell.Value <= 48 Then : cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(cell.Value, 48) : ElseIf cell.Value <= 60 Then : cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(cell.Value, 60) : ElseIf ... Where the semicolon means the new line.
